# Could not connect to daemon

Tags: synchronization

I am a newbie and still trying to figure out what i am doing.  For a couple of weeks now I've really been struggling to sync Daemom.  The blocks are painfully slow. I'm setting up a local wallet, for the first time, using a Ledger Nano S. Typically after about 24 hrs the Blocks are sitting at about 2111000.  I've force stopped the sync a number times and started from scratch.

My computer is SSD. Using Windows 10. I've excluded the moneoro files from my antivirus and quarantine settings.  I'm using monero-gui-v0.16.0.3.

At one point my sync was going fine.  The Block were down to about 1114000 after about 12hrs and then my kid interrupted the sync, and i had to start all over.  Since then the blocks have been going down painfully slow.

When i check the bitmonero log, on average it tells me the estimated time of sync is about 16 days which doesn't seem reasonable

The Daemon Log shows me: [2020-09-06 7:57 PM] 2020-09-06 23:57:34.136 I Monero 'Nitrogen Nebula' (v0.16.0.3-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
[2020-09-06 7:57 PM] 2020-09-06 23:57:51.391 I Monero 'Nitrogen Nebula' (v0.16.0.3-release)
Height: 1, target: 1 (100%)
Downloading at 0 kB/s
Next needed pruning seed: 1
0 peers
0 spans, 0 MB

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What happens if you open `monerod.exe` manually (by double clicking on it)? Make sure all other Monero related software is closed before doing this.

Comment: Thank you.  I inadvertently opened (double clicked) monerod.exe manually yesterday and it seems to have done the trick (almost).  In a 12hr period i went advanced from 2,170,000 blocks to  590,863 which is real progress. The block sync seems to be stuck at this 590,863 for a few hours now.  I'm not sure if i should just wait it out.  I'm afraid to touch anything for fear that i will lose the sync progress i've made thus far. i'm curious if there is a way to pause the sync process, for whatever reason, and resume it again?

Comment: You can type `exit` into `monerod.exe` if you have opened it manually. This will exit the daemon (monerod) and save the progress. As a side note, do you have sufficient free space on your `C:` drive?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I made sure to free up enough space on my C: drive.  I have over 100 GB available.

Comment: Are the number of blocks remaining going down though? If not, the sync may be stuck.

Comment: Over the past 2hrs the blocks remaining have gone from 590,863 to 514,828.   Slow but not stuck.

Comment: And, to be clear, you are merely running `monerod.exe` right?

Comment: My sync completed after about 26 hrs.  Thanks for the assistance dEBRUYNE.  much appreciated!!

Comment: Glad to hear and you're welcome. Let me know if you need any further assistance.